# Setting correct time settings on Liferay

Tags: glassfish, liferay, glassfish-3, liferay-6

The time on my Liferay install is incorrect. 
Where do I go to change the time settings?
I have Liferay 6 running on Glassfish 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is question on incorret time zone go to

```
Control panel -> Portal settings - Display settings
```

and change zime zone.